# Rspec/Capybara test cases are not working for multiple 'it' blocks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, integration-testing

I am  writing some integration test cases for an existing application. My test works fine if there is only one 'it' block. However, If I add more than one 'it' block it throws an error. Below is my code that works:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe 'Group' do
  before do
    visit 'http://groups.caremonkey.com/users/sign_in'
    fill_in "Email", :with => "email@example.com"
    fill_in "Password", :with => "password"
    click_button "Login"
    page.should have_link('Account')
  end
  it 'Should check all the links and functionality of groups' do
    #add new subgroup with valid data should save a new group
    find("#group-squares").click_link("Add")
    fill_in "Group Name", :with => "Melbourne futsal"
    click_on("Save")
    page.should_not have_content("can't be blank")
    page.execute_script("parent.$.fancybox.close();")
    page.should have_link('Account')

    #test edit group: should be able to update group info provided valid data are given
    first(".actual img").click
    page.should have_content("Group")
    page.should have_link("Cancel")
    fill_in "Group name", :with => "Futsal club"
    page.execute_script("$('#sub-group-color-options').find('.color23').click()")
    click_button "Save"
    click_on("Cancel")
    page.should have_link('Account')
  end
end
```

It works perfectly fine when I put all the '**it**' block together in a single 'it' block. But when I split them in different 'it' block, it stops working. For example if I split this ("test edit group: should be able to update group info provided valid data are given") test case into separate 'it' block as follows

```
 require 'spec_helper'
 describe 'Group' do
   before do
     visit 'http://groups.caremonkey.com/users/sign_in'
     fill_in "Email", :with => "email@example.com"
     fill_in "Password", :with => "password"
     click_button "Login"
     page.should have_link('Account')
   end
   it 'add new subgroup with valid data should save a new group' do
     find("#group-squares").click_link("Add")
     fill_in "Group Name", :with => "Melbourne futsal"
     click_on("Save")
     page.should_not have_content("can't be blank")
     page.execute_script("parent.$.fancybox.close();")
     page.should have_link('Account')
   end

   it 'should be able to update group info provided valid data are given' do
     first(".actual img").click
     page.should have_content("Group")
     page.should have_link("Cancel")
     fill_in "Group name", :with => "Futsal club"
     page.execute_script("$('#sub-group-color-options').find('.color23').click()")
     click_button "Save"
     click_on("Cancel")
     page.should have_link('Account')
   end
 end
```

then  rspec fails, it passes the first test, however second test gets failed throwing following error.

```
Failure/Error: visit 'http://groups.caremonkey.com/users/sign_in'
 ActionController::RoutingError:
   No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_in"
```

One more thing, I have to test all the features in remote(url: http://groups.caremonkey.com/). Because, I am writing integration tests for an existing application. In addition, I need to login to the system before I test rest of the features of my application. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you intend to make the `bash@caremonkey.com` user completely public to all on the internet?

Comment: No it wasn't intentional. I changed my user/pass just for test purpose. Thanks anyways for your concern.

Comment: Please update your question to show exactly how you have split the tests up and what the error message is.

Comment: @Shepmaster: I have update my question with error message. You can have a look at it now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you followed the Capybara documentation for [calling remote servers](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/tree/2.1.0#calling-remote-servers)? It says you should have the following:

```
Capybara.current_driver = :selenium # Or anything but rack_test, probably
Capybara.run_server = false # Don't run your app in-process
Capybara.app_host = 'http://groups.caremonkey.com/'
```

My guess is that when you have visited the site once, future `visit` calls are trying to use relative routes, which then is routed to the default server. I can't think why you would get a `ActionController::RoutingError` if you don't have some kind of Rack server running. Are you running these tests in some other Rails application?

Comment: I have done that too.. which didn't help either. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

I guess something like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe 'Group' do
  before do
    visit 'http://groups.caremonkey.com/users/sign_in'
    fill_in "Email", :with => "email@example.com"
    fill_in "Password", :with => "password"
    click_button "Login"
    page.should have_link('Account')
    find("#group-squares").click_link("Add")  #apperently both specs are "scoped" to this page
  end

  it 'Should check all the links and functionality of groups' do
    fill_in "Group Name", :with => "Melbourne futsal"
    click_on("Save")
    page.should_not have_content("can't be blank")
    page.execute_script("parent.$.fancybox.close();")
    page.should have_link('Account')
  end

  it "test edit group: should be able to update group info provided valid data are given"
    first(".actual img").click
    page.should have_content("Group")
    page.should have_link("Cancel")
    fill_in "Group name", :with => "Futsal club"
    page.execute_script("$('#sub-group-color-options').find('.color23').click()")
    click_button "Save"
    click_on("Cancel")
    page.should have_link('Account')
  end
end
```

My gut feeling tells me both test need the follow this: `find("#group-squares").click_link("Add")` so I added it to the before block This test however is cryptic, what is first(".actual img")?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, that didn't work for me. `find("#group-squares").click_link("Add")` is the link to test creation of group and `first(".actual img").click` refers to the first edit link of group. Rspec throws routing error when it tries to execute before block second time.